# icon alignment html issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, rendering

When I open http://abmatic.azurewebsites.net/Article/CMT%201125A in firefox/chrome or IE the layout of the icon in front of the download text is different. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some code here? No one will want to go to the effort of viewing the source of your website

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add vertical align to css of the icon, like this:

```
.gray-boxs h3 .glyphicon {
   margin: 0 10px 0 0;
   color: #464648;
   vertical-align: text-top;
}
```